# flex mobile project: Establish http connection to a specific url

Tags: apache-flex, http

how to establish http connection to a specific url and get data from that url in flex mobile project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function:

```
/* Function to make a generic HTTP Request
 * loc = location e.g. http://www.google.com
 * req = request 
 * type = content type
 * complete = function to execute when HTTP req returns with complete
 */
    public function httpReq(loc:String , req:String, type:String, complete:Function):void{
                /* Start the HTTP Request */
                try{
                    requestSender= new URLLoader();
                    requestSender.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
                    requestSender.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, printResponse);
                    var urlRequest :URLRequest = new URLRequest(loc);

                    /* Setup HTTP Request */
                    urlRequest.data = req;
                    urlRequest.contentType = type;
                    urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
                    requestSender.load(urlRequest); // Send the request off, when complete jump to completeHandler
                    }
                catch(e:Error){
                        trace(e.message);
                        trace(e.getStackTrace());
                    }
                }
```

Get the response:

```
/* HTTP Request complete, back with response */
private function responseHandler(event:Event):void
{
    this.requestSender = URLLoader(event.target); // Set requestSender as response
    this.output.text = this.requestSender.data; // Get its data
    trace("THE DATA IS "+this.requestSender.data);
    this.requestSender.close();
    alert.cancel();
}
```

Example call:

```
httpReq("http://www.google.com" , "requestString", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", responseHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing any research?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/index.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/developing_mobile_apps_flex.pdf

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/accessingdata/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ff2.html